# My Eee PC 900 A won't work?

Tags: linux

My laptop, and Eee PC 900 A won't work, at all. I don't know anything about computers, so I've just been pressing a bunch of random buttons. I don't know what a RAM is and all of those other terms... So if you have any suggestions, you might want to dumb it down. ^.^

Anyway, once I turn the laptop on, it flashes a bit with either a hyphen or underscore in the top left corner. After that, it turns to the starting screen that says "Starting System" but then some words along the top that are highlighted in black pop up saying, "/init: /init: 65: cannot open /mnt/dev/console: No such file" that is exactly what it says and it's driving me crazy! Nothing else happens! ;( Please help.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, I think you may want to ask a friend to have a look at it or take this to the shop you bought it. The manual that came with it may explain how to restore it the way it was when you bought it. This means losing any information you may have stored on it (messages, photos etc) that you haven't made "backup" copies of on another device.

Comment: I'm afraid [su]'s format is not very conducive to open troubleshooting like this, so you may find it difficult to troubleshoot, or this question might get closed (It's designed for more specific questions, where the issue is clearly outlined). If you reach 30 rep, you can use the [chat], which will be easier to work in if you find someone willing to help you. If you have a friend who can help you diagnose or narrow down the problem, that would also help us narrow down the problem that we're trying to fix. "Linux won't boot" is a very wide category.

Comment: Well, I've gotten to the BIOS page thing, and Dave Rook told me to click on the "Last Known Good Setting" option if there was one, but there is no option for that. There are tabs labeled "Main," "Advanced," "Security," "Boot" and "Exit," but I am unsure of what to do now. I don't know what to enable and what to disable...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you unplug everything (other than power) - so no USB, no drive in DVD (if it has one) or any external device.

Straight after turning on your PC, press del (delete) over and over again; this will let you enter the BIOS. There is usually an option to use "Last known good settings". Select this, and then press F10 to exit and save. Then try to load the PC up and see if that helps.

If you're this unsure with computers though it may be more productive to ask some one to help you or take it to a computer shop although I will try to help as much as I can.

Comment: @David Rook- Ah, I tried it and it didn't work. I would take it somewhere but I've done that before and they didn't do anything. They told me to read through the manual and figure it out. Well, not necessarily like that, but kind of like that. If you have any other suggestions that are the slightest bit basic, I'll be able to figure it out... Most likely.

Comment: And the BIOS page didn't stay up long enough for me to click or select anything. :/

Comment: OK - the BIOS isn't a message - it is like a program which stays open until the user shuts it. Please try again, the first time pressing F2, and if this doesn't work, try F11

Comment: Alright. I'm on the BIOS Setup Utility page. there are these tabs labeled "Main, Advanced, Security, Boot, and Exit." I know what to do to exit, but I'm not seeing any "Last Known Good Settings."

Comment: The Last Known Good menu option is not a bios feature, it's a Windows boot feature.  If you press F8 several times just after the bios startup screen disappears, you should get an advanced Windows boot menu, which includes Last Known Good configuration as an option.  Sometimes that does solve the problem.

Comment: Ahh... Rhea, Stabledog is right but in Bios press F9 which should load default setting. Rhea, are you on Windows or Linux?